# Postgresql database query to Ruby active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There are tables audits and audit_statuses, and need to fetch the data which are not common in both. I already have a query that works in postgresql , how to convert convert it into Ruby active record .

> the following is the Psql query

```
SELECT a.name as status,count(b.audit_status_id) as count 
FROM audit_statuses as a,audits as b 
WHERE a.id=b.audit_status_id 
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Comment: are you looking to have the query in rails return objects, or do you want just the raw results set back?  if the latter, check out the execute method for method the connection in active record.

Comment: i need exact converted ruby code which i can use instead of find_by_sql(".....")

Comment: could you post association of your tables ?

Comment: <--audit_status table-->
id - integer,
name -string

<--audit table-->
id – integer,
audit_status_id -integer

Comment: No, I mean association on your models. audit `belongs_to` audit_status, and audit_status `has_many` audits ?

Comment: yup exactly..audit belongs_to audit_status, and audit_status has_many audits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your association models are Audit `belongs_to` Audit_status, and Audit_status `has_many` Audits, aren't there? And You want to get counts how many Audit_statuses owned by Audit, won't you?

If yes, you should use `counter_cache` read this about [belongs_to Association Reference #counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)

> Although the :counter_cache option is specified on the model that
>   includes the belongs_to declaration, the actual column must be added
>   to the associated model. In the case above, you would need to add a
>   column named count_audit to the Audit_status model

Add `count_audit` attribute to `audit_statuses` table by running :

```
rails g migration AddCountAuditToAuditStatuses count_audit:integer
```

and run `rake db:migrate`

On your models looks like :

```
class Audit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :audit_status_id, :status
  belongs_to :audit_status, :counter_cache => :count_audit
end

class AuditStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count_audit, :name

  has_many :audits
end
```

Example create one record of `audit_status`

```
irb(main):001:0> audit_status = AuditStatus.create!(:name => "John Noe")
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (114.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "audit_statuses" ("count_audit", "created_at", "name", "up
dated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["count_audit", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 06 Jun
 2014 15:17:49 WIB +07:00], ["name", "John Noe"], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 15:17:49 WIB +07:0
0]]
  ←[1m←[36m (17.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
=> #<AuditStatus id: 1, name: "John Noe", count_audit: nil, created_at: "2014-06-06 08:17:49", updat
ed_at: "2014-06-06 08:17:49">
```

And create two records of audit, and get `audit_status.id` for `audit_status_id`

```
irb(main):002:0> audit = Audit.create!({:audit_status_id => audit_status.id, :status => true})
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (6.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO "audits" ("audit_status_id", "created_at", "status", "up
dated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"←[0m  [["audit_status_id", 1], ["created_at", Fri,
06 Jun 2014 15:19:00 WIB +07:00], ["status", true], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 15:19:00 WIB +07
:00]]
  ←[1m←[35mAuditStatus Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "audit_statuses".* FROM "audit_statuses" WHERE "audi
t_statuses"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUPDATE "audit_statuses" SET "count_audit" = COALESCE("count_audit",
0) + 1 WHERE "audit_statuses"."id" = 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (1.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT
=> #<Audit id: 1, audit_status_id: 1, status: true, created_at: "2014-06-06 08:19:00", updated_at: "
2014-06-06 08:19:00">
irb(main):003:0> audit = Audit.create!({:audit_status_id => audit_status.id, :status => false})
  ←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "audits" ("audit_status_id", "created_at", "status", "update
d_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["audit_status_id", 1], ["created_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2
014 15:19:23 WIB +07:00], ["status", false], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 15:19:23 WIB +07:00]]
  ←[1m←[36mAuditStatus Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "audit_statuses".* FROM "audit_statuses" WHERE "
audit_statuses"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  UPDATE "audit_statuses" SET "count_audit" = COALESCE("count_audit", 0) +
 1 WHERE "audit_statuses"."id" = 1
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
=> #<Audit id: 2, audit_status_id: 1, status: false, created_at: "2014-06-06 08:19:23", updated_at:
"2014-06-06 08:19:23">
```

So, you only call audit_status's records looks like :

```
irb(main):004:0> @audit_statuses = AuditStatus.all
  ←[1m←[35mAuditStatus Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "audit_statuses".* FROM "audit_statuses"
=> [#<AuditStatus id: 1, name: "John Noe", count_audit: 2, created_at: "2014-06-06 08:17:49", update
d_at: "2014-06-06 08:17:49">]
```

Comment: thanks for u r reply.but i solvethe problem in another way.am adding dat also

Comment: @user3713745 : But the best practice like your case seems to be use `counter_cache`. It does exactly what you want to do, and it is built-in into ActiveRecord instead `Audit.joins( :audit_status).select("name as status,count(audit_status_id) as count").group(:name)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@audit_status = Audit.joins( :audit_status).select("name as status,count(audit_status_id) as count").group(:name)
```